# How to get rid of "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log2' "

Tags: pandas, lambda, seaborn

Say I have a data frame with columns of  `min value` =36884326.0, and `max value` =6619162563.0, which I need to plot as box plot, so I tried to log transform the values, as follows,

```
diff["values"]     = diff['value'].apply(lambda x: (x+1))
diff["log_values"] = diff['values'].apply(lambda x: x.log2(x))
```

However, the above lines are throwing the error as follows,

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-fe4e1d2286b0> in <module>
      1 diff['value'].max()
      2 diff["values"]     = diff['value'].apply(lambda x: (x+1))
----> 3 diff["log_values"] = diff['values'].apply(lambda x: x.log2(x))

~/software/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3195 
   3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-28-fe4e1d2286b0> in <lambda>(x)
      1 diff['value'].max()
      2 diff["values"]     = diff['value'].apply(lambda x: (x+1))
----> 3 diff["log_values"] = diff['values'].apply(lambda x: x.log2(x))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log2'
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: change to `.apply(lambda x: np.log2(x))` ..?

Comment: Thank you  @ChrisA, it was the issue I need numpy to apply the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `numpy.log2` function to aplly, please, check sintaxis [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.log2.html).